# Can we please add http://sqa.stackexchange.com as a migration target?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Consider [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139712/is-performance-testing-applicable-to-a-qa-or-business-user-testing).

It would be a perfect candidate for the Software QA Stack Exchange site.

So can we please add http://sqa.stackexchange.com as a migration target?

Comment: How's that question off topic for Programmers?

Comment: Also consider that SQA is still a beta site. Migrating questions that are on-topic here to a beta site might result in the loss of a good/useful question and its answers if the site is shut down.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: But as it exists today, SQA.SE is an afterthought for most. It needs some love.

Comment: Beta sites are *never* made migration targets.

Comment: @JimG. They need to build their own community, then, by drawing in subject matter experts. If they launch, we/Stack Exchange can reconsider topicality of SQA questions and migration paths. In the meantime, developer testing, quality assurance, and software engineering are on-topic here. Both the original question and edit question fall into those categories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm Tim Post, a community manager for Stack Exchange. I'd like to take a few moments to answer this, and explain a bit about migration paths.

Migration paths between sites are something that we're very cautious to establish, we put them in place only when we're certain that the conduit will:

- Help ease confusion for users that ask a question on a site that overlaps with another, ensuring a great question is sent where it will receive the best answers without much additional effort on the part of the question author,
- Be largely beneficial to the target site,
- Not become a party to unresolved topic disputes on the originating site, or between the originating and target site.

You'll notice, Programmers is no longer a migration target from Stack Overflow, neither is Server Fault. However, LaTEX and Sharepoint *are*. Questions about the latter are agreed by all concerned to be more on topic for their respective sites, that's why folks put so much effort into getting those sites created.

With that being said, we don't establish migration paths to a site that is still in its beta period. We don't want to send content from one site to another unless we're certain that the target site is a permanent fixture. There are exceptions to this; moderators *can* migrate relatively new questions to sites not in the current migration path, but this ability should be used sparingly. A question should be of much better than average quality, and all hope of it being on topic for the current site should be exhausted prior to going around the established routes.

When SQA comes out of beta, this is something that we can revisit. However, for now, it's simply not possible to add a migration path between Programmers and SQA.

Comment: @JimG. btw, you can always flag for moderation attention and ask for the question to be migrated to SQA (or any other site). We'll generally avoid migrating away questions that are on topic on Programmers, but if the question hasn't received a good answer in a few days (a week?), then I don't see why we shouldn't send it to another site where it might get more attention. If you happen upon good SQA questions that have gone unnoticed for a while on Programmers, feel free to use the custom mod attention flag.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: Thanks, Yannis. Will do.