# Migration path to Code Review please?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

I know we don't want too many migration paths, and we definitely don't want ones that are likely to leech away our *good* questions, but I think of all the technology related websites, the scope of Code Review actually has likely the least overlap with us of any others.

No part of our site scope is reviewing written completed *code*, architecture sure but not *code*.

And no part of code reviews site is *doing anything else at all*.

We don't get questions for this migration often, but I just saw one and it's going to be migrated to SO (even though it's totally working code) likely just because we have a migration path to SO but not CR.

So, just a thought.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Could you leave a comment regarding the satus change? Just curious why this migration path is no longer being considered.

Comment: Nothing really changed @BartvanIngenSchenau, except for the tag. All our other "migration to beta site" Meta questions are [status-declined], so I thought [status-deferred] here might be a bit confusing. If CR makes it out of beta, we'll certainly revisit this.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5785/can-we-please-add-project-management-as-a-migration-path-from-programmers/5786#5786), there are never migration paths to Beta sites. This seems like a reasonable idea, assuming that Code Review gets out of Beta, and we should revisit this then. In the mean time, if there's an exceptional post that you feel belongs on Code Review, flag it for moderator attention - we can still migrate to Code Review.

Comment: Ah right, I always forget CR is beta because it's in the only released form it ever will be due to the community that never showed up, but it will never go away due to the community that *is* there... Ah well, thanks!

Comment: @JimmyHoffa It's doing Okay-Excellent on all of the Area 51 metrics. For the ones that it's Okay on, it's not that far off from Excellent. It may still come out of Beta.

Comment: ...and it only took 2 years! lol