# CR isn't in beta - migration path to them now?

Tags: feature-request, migration

**This was previously declined as CR.SE was in beta and migrations to beta sites are not allowed. CR is no longer in beta! Congratulations to CR!**

I know we don't want too many migration paths, and we definitely don't want ones that are likely to leech away our *good* questions, but I think of all the technology related websites, the scope of Code Review actually has likely the least overlap with us of any others.

No part of our site scope is reviewing written completed *code*, architecture sure but not *code*.

And no part of code reviews site is *doing anything else at all*.

We don't get questions for this migration often, but I've seen ones migrated to SO with totally working code, just because we have a migration path to SO but not CR.

Related:

[Migration path to Code Review please?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5901/35276)

Comment: It would help to compile a list of recent questions (say, 90 days or younger) that would be migration candidates (whether they were migrated or not).

Comment: if we set a majority requirement of 4 votes (like SO does to their migrations) instead of standard 3, it would be interesting to try

Comment: for reference: a similar idea has recieved a ["no migrations" for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311348/what-is-the-latest-on-adding-code-review-to-off-topic-migration-options)

Answer (score 9):

For reference, as of this writing migrations to CodeReview in the past 90 days shows 5 sent, of which 2 were rejected (40%).  Which also happens to be CodeReview's rate with us.

Away (all 10k links - Roomba deletes successful migrations after 30 days):

- [P.SE Function to return a string - Which is cleaner?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307311/function-to-return-a-string-which-is-cleaner?noredirect=1) ([CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116696/choosing-a-css-class-based-on-an-http-status-code))
- [P.SE Better way to build SQL query from form input?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307307/better-way-to-build-sql-query-from-form-input?noredirect=1) ([CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116694/build-sql-query-criteria-from-form-input))
- [P.SE I wrote a sleep() function! Is it harmless and cross-platform?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/305939/40980) ([rejected](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115192/sleep-function)) (10ks deleted)
- [P.SE How can I make the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm more efficient?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305454/how-can-i-make-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm-more-efficient?noredirect=1) ([CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114485/extending-sieve-of-eratosthenes-beyond-a-billion))
- [P.SE Jumping into C++, TIC TAC TOE. How is my code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304911/jumping-into-c-tic-tac-toe-how-is-my-code?noredirect=1) ([rejected](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113723/jumping-into-c-tic-tac-toe-how-is-my-code)) (op deleted)

And since I'm in the tools, the CR to P.SE migrations in the last 90 days:

- [Does my code still break encapsulation and uses getters/setters instead of the TellDontAsk principle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309160/does-my-code-still-break-encapsulation-and-uses-getters-setters-instead-of-the-t)
- [Generating dual .xlsx files and .htm pages of the same data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306289/generating-dual-xlsx-files-and-htm-pages-of-the-same-data)
- [Testing using mocking, must I mock all dependencies too?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306277/testing-using-mocking-must-i-mock-all-dependencies-too)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304643/how-much-implementation-should-i-provide-in-an-abstract-class (rejected)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304470/factoryclass-versus-factorymethod-in-pojo (rejected)

Answer (score 8):

I would like to present this chart from [Checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1957/42632) first:

[image: chart]

As you can see, the metaphorical *distance* in scope between Programmers and Code Review is significant. From a CR regular standpoint, I can say for myself that we do get, *on occasion*, a question which is off-topic at CR but could be on-topic at Programmers *(most off-topic Qs we get are broken code/"give-me-the-code")*

When this happens, normally one of us will hop over to The Whiteboard to ask if it would be a good migration candidate, and if it is the case, mods move forward with manual migration. This happens... once a week at the most, I'd say. I'm not a regular at Programmers so I cannot speak on your behalf, but I think the important question is:

> **Does the volume of off-topic on Programmers, on-topic on Code Review questions justify a migration path?**

Please reference [MichaelT's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7901/140090) for migration stats between Programmers and Code Review.

Comment: As a 10k user on code review, you've got the stats too... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats (go to /review, click on tools on the left side (next to the word 'review'), explore)

Comment: @MichaelT thanks for the link, I didn't realize that was there. I added a link to your answer in my post as well, thanks for taking the time to put those together.

Answer (score 5):

I'm somewhat familiar with CR, with close to 1k rep there now.

I think there are a very small minority of questions here asking for code review which would be suited for CR.

Most of them are not functioning, fully working code that is a "please help me improve this" type of thing - most of them are, "here's code that sorta works, plz help me fix/add to it."